# Empty CSV after Recode via BATCH [UCS -> UTF]

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, csv

I want to recode a CSV File from UCS to UTF-8 via Batch, if I use this code in my Batch File I just receive a empty file..

```
iconv -f UCS-2 -t UTF-8 -c export_RV-RP.csv > export_RV-RP2.csv
```

Can someone tell why?

thanks

Comment: Remove the -c switch, remove the redirect to file and see the output to console. Some message, error, ... any output?

Comment: It says the ICONV coundn't be found..

Comment: No iconv, no conversion, no data in output file. Do you have a copy of iconv in your system?

Comment: No, I've never delete that file. Is there a way to reinstall just the dll?

Comment: iconv is not included in windows. You need to download it and place in path (or include the full path when calling the program). The gnuWin32 project includes a win32 port of the tool (see [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm)). You have a setup download or a non install binaries/dependencies downloads.